# sql server developer edition

Tags: sql-server-2005

Just wondering does the 4GB limit apply to this edition or is it 'fully functional'?

Thanks.

Christian

Comment: 4GB limit only applies to Express Edition. We have some fatmungous DBs running from Developer Edition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Developer edition is Enterprise edition, just a difference license. So yes, fully functional

Anyway, what 4GB limit...? Do you mean the *Express* edition 4GB file limit or some RAM limitation?

Comment: In Express Edition there is a 4GB limit for individual mdf files I think.

Comment: @Martin Smith: yes, I realised and edited while you posted the comment. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No.

Developer edition is the same as Enterprise except (1) restricted EULA: for development and test only, and (2) can be installed on client editions of Windows.